# Accents issue doc to txt

Tags: php, convertapi

First I want to convert pdf file to html, but the api can't do that.

So I tried to convert pdf to txt. I have a lot of problems with multiple space or line...
So I tried (again) to convert pdf to word and word. The word is perfect.

Unfortunately, ConvertApi can't convert word to html... and I can found a free library to convert word to html.

So I tried (again and again) to convert word to txt.
Now I have accents problems on the txt file :

- régime become r‚gime
- matière become matiŠres
- contrôle become contr“le

Comment: SOunds like an encoding issue.

Comment: By `word` do you mean Microsoft Word?

Comment: Yes, it's a .doc file

Comment: @ThomasDurand Please contact the ConvertAPI support to solve this problem https://www.convertapi.com/support

Comment: I did that and I'm waiting return...

Comment: The Word to HTML is now supported at https://www.convertapi.com/docx-to-html